# Tooltip in ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this little progress bar with tooltip.

```
<div class="progress progress-mini tip" title="" data-original-title="70%">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%;"></div>
</div>
```

If I put it directly in page it works.

But when i get it with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ajax/getLists.php",
    datatype: "html",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#ajaxspinner').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#ajaxspinner').hide();
        $('.container-fluid #heading').after(data);
    }
});
```

PHP file (getLists.php):

```
<?php
echo '<div class="progress progress-mini tip" title="" data-original-title="70%"><div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%;"></div></div>';
?>
```

Tooltip doesn't show.

(I'm new to jquery and I can't find solution)

Comment: are you getting anything in your data object? You can use console.log(data) in success: to see what you are getting. My guess is you are not getting anything back so you will need to check your getLists.php

Comment: which tooltip plugin you use? The problem I can see is, you need to initialize the tooltip again within the success handler, since its been loaded dynamically.

Comment: @code-jaff reinitializing helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using a tooltip plugin for jquery. And that you followed the demo and initialized it on document ready, is that it?
If so, you should initialize your plugin after loading the content. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/ajax/getLists.php",
datatype: "html",
beforeSend: function() {
    $('#ajaxspinner').show();
},
success: function(data) {
    $('#ajaxspinner').hide();
    $('.container-fluid #heading').after(data);
    $.tooltipPluginInit('.tip'); // whatever
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to redefine tooltips.

If you have something like `$(".tip").tooltip()` somewhere, it runs when page loads and registers already-on-page `class=tip` tooltips. So when you append some using Ajax, they are not registered by `.tooltip()`.

Possible solution: use [Livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) - it monitors DOM changes and registers calls on appended elements.

Then you would define tooltips like that:

```
$(".tip").livequery(function(){
     $(this).tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Thx, for this, but in ajax success part, i just added $(".tip").tooltip();

Comment: OK, I thought about your workaround, but I had problem with it (but not with tooltips), becouse it was redeclared on all `.tip`, not just on those added. So for example click events were fired twice on    original (before ajax existing) elements.

Answer (score -1):

try putting getLists.php file in the same directory with the file that's called ajax.

Comment: Ajax loads PHP file, and content in it. And I can see loaded content but jquery events are not working. In this case, tooltip is not shown on mouserover div.

Comment: do u use any other jquery files, like jquery.min.js or any other jquery functions.

Comment: this should have been a comment, and irrelevant to the question since the path was clearly stated by OP